# Jenkins plugin development - customizing default behaviour of Pipeline Snippet Generator

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

There is a snippet generator available under the following url:

http://<your-jenkins-instance>/job/<your-job>/pipeline-syntax/

It will generate the pipeline step snippet based on the data you enter on a form. Let's look at `libraryResource` step, as that will be a good example.  If we do not fill in `Character encoding`, it will not be included in the generated snippet. This the behaviour I'm trying to implement in a custom plugin, to no avail. The way it works in my plugin is that every unset variable is always translated into empty in the generated snippet, e.g. `value: ''` rather than omited altogether.

I have been looking at the code and cannot find anything that would override the default behaviour that I've observed:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/libs/ResourceStep/config.jelly

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/libs/ResourceStep.java

Any clues how to enforce skipping unset values while generating the snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, value is skipped during the generation of snippet if it is `null`, so in case of `ResourceStep.encoding` it is converted to null in method

```
@DataBoundSetter public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
    this.encoding = Util.fixEmptyAndTrim(encoding);
}
```

see https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/workflow-cps-global-lib-2.15/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/libs/ResourceStep.java#L67

More information You can find here:
https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/plugin-development/pipeline-integration/